# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() magento version 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> [Exception]   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   G:\workspace1\magento2-
>   alexa\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Config\Processor\Fallback.php
>   on li   ne 121
>
> setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

Comment: You're going to need to give more information about this error.  What version of Magento 2?  Do you have any custom modules installed?

Comment: The version is magento 2.1.3 no.. there is no custom modules installed ... just fresh magento vagrant box up then just try to install magento-2 sample data... then this errors shows up

Comment: I am having the same issue @user2366074 Did you solve it?

Comment: I know it sounds a bit silly but, do you have an `app/etc/env.php` in place? Is everything fine in there?